# Can I use std::max_element() on std::deque in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, deque

Can I code like `std::max_element(std::begin(my_deque), std::end(my_deque))`?

I am asking because I know deque is not guaranteed to store continuously, so I want to know if it will behave correctly when using functions involving iterator like `std::max_element`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you worried that it won't be guaranteed to always work?

Comment: they spec only requires `class ForwardIt` so this should work for any collection that implements forward iteration. It has nothing to do with contiguous storage at all.

Comment: `std::max_elements` only requires a forward iterator see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: `max_element` only requires that the iterator is a ForwardIterator. It does not require random access/data continuitiy

Comment: The whole point of using iterators rather than pointers is to make this kind of stuff work.

Comment: There's actually a second point to iterators: to not compile code which can't work. `std::sort` will fail to compile, if you pass Forward Iterators.

Comment: Achtung grammar Nazi… if you give me a gold bar every day, and I put it on a heap in my basement, I'm storing them continuously. If you give me 100 gold bars, and I put them all in a row, I am storing them contiguously. Either way you may assume I will be very grateful for all the gold. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) has a signature in the form of

```
template<class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator max_element(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);
```

From the template type name we know that it requires a forward iterator.  Per [container.requirements.general]-Table 96 we know that `std::deque` uses

> any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements

So since it uses a forward iterator or better it will always be okay.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it will work correctly. The overload of `std::max_element` that will be invoked in this case is

```
template< class ForwardIt > 
ForwardIt max_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last);
```

The only requirements on the iterators are

> `first`, `last`    -   forward iterators defining the range to examine

So there is no requirement about random access iterators, only forward iterators.

Comment: You're right about ``max_element`` requiring forward iterators only, however there seems to be some confusion about the category of ``std::deque`` iterators (they're random access). Having random access iterators does not imply contiguous storage.